# How to insert code inside certain div in ckeditor rather than inserting it at cusor position?

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor

I am trying to create buttons for ckeditor that will add rows and columns of contents to the editor using 960.gs grid system.

I need a way to insert the generated code into certain div that already exists in the editor window not just at the cursor.

For example, We have this code in the editor:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid_12">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I click my button, This code is generated:

```
<div class="grid_3"></div>
```

I need the generated code to be inserted into the div with class (grid_12). Whatever the position of the cursor is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ckeditor seems to have the normal DOM model for the content being edited, you should be able to do something like this:

```
var oEditor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
var element = oEditor.document.getById('myElement');
var grid_3 = new CKEDITOR.dom.element('div');
grid_3.setAttributes({'class' : 'grid_3'});
element.append(grid_3);
```

Here I did assume you'd use an id for the grid_12 element, if you wouldn't it's not possible to do it without fetching the cursors position and extracting the specified div using that then...

Comment: @alhoseany Any errors you get? If possible, a live example could help solve the problem sooner.

Comment: it does not give any errors, i tried to alert the element, it gives me this message: "object[object]".

Comment: @alhoseany The only issue I encountered when I just tested my code was that instead of calling the CKEDITOR.document for the element, I had to select the active editor first, but otherwise it just inserted a div with class grid_3 to the element with the myElement id. Note that there must be an ID assigned to your div, otherwise it obviously won't work, due to the reason mentioned in the first post (updated the code in original post)